Ошибка при работе с OpenCV: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code
MacBook Air Apple M2
Первый файл
import cv2
import datetime


def microscope_connection():
    try:
        print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Соединение с микроскопом.")
        camera_data_stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        if not camera_data_stream.isOpened():
            print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Ошибка соединения с микроскопом.\n")
            exit()
        else:
            print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Соединение с микроскопом установлено.\n")
            return camera_data_stream

    except ImportError as e:
        print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Ошибка импорта библиотеки: {e}.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Неизвестная ошибка: {e}.")

Второй файл
import os
import cv2
import datetime

from Project.Station.Microscope.connection import microscope_connection


def microscope_screenshot(save_path, image_name):
    connection = microscope_connection()

    try:
        print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Чтение кадра с активного микроскопа.")
        ret, frame = connection.read()

        if ret:
            screenshot_filename = os.path.join(save_path, str(image_name))

            cv2.imwrite(screenshot_filename, frame)
            cv2.imshow('Microscope', frame)
            cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        else:
            print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Не удалось сохранить кадр.")

        print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Сохранение кадра с активного микроскопа.\n")

    except cv2.error as e:
        print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Ошибка при работе с OpenCV: {e}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Неизвестная ошибка: {e}")

    finally:
        connection.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Нужно прикладывать полный трейс ошибки к вопросу.

И какой у вас вопрос?
